# can't open video by videocapture in android studio

Tags: android

I'm trying use videocaptur to open video ,but without success. 
I tried different video avi codec.

```
 public void OnBtnStart(View view) {
        String videopath = "android.resource://com.example.msi.mhltryagain/"+R.raw.testmjpeg;

        VideoView videoview = (android.widget.VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.msi.mhltryagain/"+R.raw.test);
        videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoview.start();


        VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture(videopath);
        boolean capGrab = cap.grab();
        if (cap.isOpened()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"is opened",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"isn't opened"+capGrab,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

The video path is certainly good because it correctly plays the test video. When i press the button is displayed "isnt'opened false". Why video can't by opened?